# WPF WebBrowser execCommand("styleWithCSS")

Tags: css, wpf, webbrowser-control, execcommand

I am trying to set some arbitrary css onto an element in wpf's WebBrowser

here's the code

```
Dim hd As IHTMLDocument2 = wb.Document
hd.execCommand("styleWithCSS", False, CObj("margin:0px"))
```

but i get an error

> Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040100 (DRAGDROP_E_NOTREGISTERED))

other simple commands such as `cut` do work

please advise

Comment: anybody ever encoutered this? any suggestions? thanks!